Обособление причастного оборота в сложном предложении
Как обособлять причастный оборот в сложном предложении при подобном случае?

Незнакомка снова задала тот самый вопрос, и(,) взвинченный до предела,
он ударил кулаком по столу.

Нужна ли запятая после и?

Запятая нужна.
Определительный оборот, стоящий после сочинительного союза (и, или, но и др.), но не связанный с ним, отделяется от него запятой по общему правилу:
Он не чувствовал склонности к чиновничеству и, одарённый выдающимся талантом наблюдения, прекрасно знал свою среду (Герц.).
